# CSI driver in AKS - Issue with CRDS while helm install of csi driver

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, csi-driver

Unable to continue with install: CustomResourceDefinition "volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release:

invalid ownership metadata; label validation error: missing key "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": must be set to "Helm"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to xxx driver

annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "hubs-driver"

Comment: The error message indicates that the CustomResourceDefinition "volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io" already exists and cannot be imported into the current release due to invalid ownership metadata.  delete the existing CustomResourceDefinition and then reinstall the CSI driver with the correct ownership metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the `volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io` CRD already exists but lacks specific labels and annotations required by Helm for management.

There are two ways to resolving this-
*Deleting the CRD* or *Updating CRD Metadata*

where deleting and reinstalling the crd is the easier method

```
kubectl delete crd volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io
```

After deletion, you can retry installing the CSI driver using Helm, ensuring it creates a new CRD with the correct metadata.
[image]

Second way i.e. to update the existing CRD, use the command

```
kubectl edit crd volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io
```

i.e.
Open the CRD for editing using command `kubectl edit crd volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io`

Look for the `metadata:` section near the top of the CRD definition. Inside the `metadata:` section, you'll find `labels:` and `annotations:` subsections. Add your missing labels and annotations accordingly. If they don't exist, you will need to create them.

[image]

[image]

and save your changes

```
kubectl get crd volumesnapshotclasses.snapshot.storage.k8s.io -o yaml
```

[image]

Reference :
[CSI driver using helm](https://secrets-store-csi-driver.sigs.k8s.io/getting-started/installation)